# App store submission error Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am receiving the following error from XCode 8.1 when trying to submit a previously successful submitted app version upgrade:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Particle.app/Particle_armv7' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
>   ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Particle.app/Particle_armv7' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

I did not modify anything in regards to architectures this build.
Any idea where I should look to solve this problem?

Comment: have yo tried answers for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222102/iphone-app-submitting-error-itms-90171-invalid-bundle-structure-constants-o

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when a static library file is mistakenly copied into the app bundle.

You should link the libYourLibrary.a static library via a Link Binary with Libraries build phase.

It should **NOT** be added to the target's **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that there was an extra build variant specified as "armv7" in the build settings. No idea why. Reverting to "normal" only fixed this issue.

from `project.pbxproj`:

```
            buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
-               BUILD_VARIANTS = (
-                   armv7,
-                   normal,
-               );
+               BUILD_VARIANTS = normal;
```

removed lines marked with - added lines with +

Issue - two binaries were included in bundle:

[image]

Fix - make sure only "normal" is under Build variants:

[image: make sure only "normal" is under Build variants]