# Kotlin Multiplatform - ERROR ITMS-90171: Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, app-store, kotlin-multiplatform

I've a problem trying to distribute my iOS app with Kotlin Multiplatform on the Apple App Store:

[image: ERROR]

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Smiledu_app.app/Frameworks/shared.framework/shared' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

[image]
[image]

I checked that it doesn't exist in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

[image]

This is my build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0")
}

configurations {
    create("compileClasspath")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

val libName = "shared"

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries.framework(libName)
    }

    val coroutinesVersion = "1.4.1-native-mt"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
    val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"
    val sqlDelightVersion = "1.4.3"
    val reactive_version = "1.1.18"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")

                // Coroutines
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.2")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")

                //  KTOR
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")

                // SQLDELIGHT
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")

                // Reactive
                implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:$reactive_version")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")

                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")

                implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.2")

                // HTTP
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }

        all {
            languageSettings.apply {
                progressiveMode = true
                useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
                useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi")
            }
        }
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)

sqldelight {
    database("SmileduDataBase") {
        packageName = "com.example.smiledu"
        schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/commonMain/db/databases")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can you please check if your `shared.framework` is included in ` Copy Bundle Resources`  Steps :- `your target app` -> `Build Phases` -> `Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't exist in Copy Bundle Resources. 
I've updated the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558866/app-store-submission-error-invalid-bundle-structure have a look at this

Comment: Hello, @SebastianPeredoMurga! There was a similar thread at the kotlinlang Slack(get invitation [here](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up?_ga=2.153206904.1185440770.1614154171-1780229624.1610358929)). I'm posting here both link to the original thread([link](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C3PQML5NU/p1612793011373400)), and a quote:

Comment: `This issue for me was caused by including the framework in the bundle. Ie, I was copying the .framework file into the app bundle. This isn’t necessary as the framework is statically linked against the main app binary.
Most likely, you have a folder containing the .framework that you copied into your project (like an “external” or “ThirdParty”). That folder should not have membership to any target.`

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue please ?

Answer (score 2):

Removing your "shared.framework" from "Embed Frameworks" section might solve your issue. Make sure you validate the build locally before pushing it to TestFlight.

Comment: I don't have an Embed Frameworks build phase and yet I'm getting this error. Any clue on how to fix it please ? I'm on KMM project with cocoapods